# Permission denied (publickey) I still get an error

Tags: git, github, ssh

I keep getting this error in git. I have read and tried very many things but none seems to work (changed 700 or 600 permissions, I selected only the rsa key with the -i option, I did ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ...)

Can anyone help?

thanks

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8h 28 May 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/myusername/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-    6+squeeze1+github8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github8 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

if I do:

```
ssh-add -l
```

I get

```
2048 60:2f:84:01:91:db:f7:83:fa:e0:a2:9a:55:49:85:ad /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

I added in the .bashrc

```
!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
```

and now I have a .ssh/config file like this:

```
#  personal account
#
Host personal.repositoryhosting.com
Hostname personal.repositoryhosting.com
IdentitiesOnly yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

#
```

Comment: personal.repositoryhosting.com has nothing to do with github. When you are doing `ssh -vT git@github.com`, you only need to check if you have added your public key to your GitHub profile. (https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Removed my .ssh file and regenerated keys. Still having the issue. I'm using gitlab and have tried numerous things. None working as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the id_dsa (or id_rsa) are your private keys, and the corresponding file with '.pub' on the end is your public key.

What is your ~/.ssh/personal_key and how does it relate to your public/private key?
 - and does your ssh agent know about it?

Comment: Indeed. I think `personal_key` is a mistake on OPs part.

Comment: Hi thanks. you mean there should be IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa ? It still does not work with that.

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment? and if its an answer how does it solve the above issue?

Comment: @Craicerjack: Both. It solves the above issue by educating the user, however note that the user has since edited their question, so my answer is probably out of date.

Answer (score 0):

removed my old .ssh folder - back it up. might not be ideal depending on the number of ssh keys you have and what they are for.

```
craicerjack@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm -rf .ssh
```

cd back into your project directory

```
git init

touch README

git push -u origin master

The authenticity of host 'your_host' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is b2:9f:1a:8c:13:9b:1f:a2:64:a9:5c:db:61:a5:04:bb.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Warning: Permanently added 'your_host' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

This creates a new .ssh dir with known_hosts file.
cd into .ssh

```
craicerjack@ubuntu:~$ cd ~/.ssh
```

Next create a new key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

via https://gitlab.deri.ie/help/ssh on gitlab
or  https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys on github.

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/carlos/.ssh/id_rsa): (you can leave this blank if you are in your .ssh dir, otherwise choose where to save the key)
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): (leave this blank if you wish)
Enter same passphrase again: (leave this blankif you wish)
Your identification has been saved in /home/carlos/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/carlos/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

use this to dump the key to your console and then copy it:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

go to your account in gitlab or github.
gitlab - https://gitlab.deri.ie/profile/keys
github - https://github.com/settings/ssh

and click on add ssh key

paste your new key in and you should be good to go. This worked for me anyway.